# Viewing list wrong on firefox

Tags: html, css

So i have this problem:

-On Chrome its showing this:

'''
  [image]
'''

-On Mozzila Firefox its showing this:

'''
  [image]
'''

I want to look like on chrome does on every platform.

```html
<h3>Servicii</h3>
</br>
<ul>
<li><a href="#><h4 style="color:#2e3760;">Beneficiari publici</h4></a></li>
<li><a href="#"><h4 style="color:#2e3760;">Beneficiari privati</h4></a></li>
<li><a href="#"><h4 style="color:#2e3760;">HelpDesk</h4></a></li>
</ul>
```

Firefox doesnt like the heading tag inside `<a>` tag, it seems.

Comment: `</br>` is invalid HTML.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Headings <del>can't</del> shouldn't be nested inside a phrasing content like a link or weird layout issues could happen, so try this structure instead

```
<h3>Servicii</h3>
<br>
<ul>
<li><h4 style="color:#2e3760;"><a href="#>Beneficiari publici</a></h4></li>
<li><h4 style="color:#2e3760;"><a href="#>Beneficiari privati</a></h4></li>
<li><h4 style="color:#2e3760;"><a href="#">HelpDesk</a></h4></li>
</ul>
```

As a side note, there's no a `</br>` tag

Comment: I swear i tried this already and it didnt work. But now it does. So thank you!

Comment: But now the text wont get the color i need, even if i put style color inside ```<a>```

Comment: It works when putting style color inside ```<a>``` tag. I was writing it wrong.

Comment: _“Headings can't be nested inside a phrasing content like a link”_ - they can in HTML5, that has lifted a lot of those restrictions HTML 4.01 had in regard to inline vs block.

Comment: Well I didn't recall this, so even of the op solved the problem I'm going to delete my answer, @Catalin if you remove the tick I can delete my answer, thank you

Answer (score 1):

```html
<h3>Servicii</h3>
<br>
<ul>
  <li><h4><a href="#" style= "color:#2e3760;" >Beneficiari publici</a></h4></li>
  <li><h4><a href="#" style= "color:#2e3760;" >Beneficiari privati</a></h4></li>
  <li><h4><a href="#" style= "color:#2e3760;" >Help Desk</a></h4></li>
</ul>
```

You can not use "Headings inside of an "Anchor" tag but you can use Anchor tag inside of a heading like my code. and sometimes you could face a problem with colors. It's better to define style on an inside element like I declared color inside a tag.